# Color manipulation when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to dynamically change the color of text when the slider radio
button is checked or unchecked. My goal is for the text to change color when the slider is active or not. Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/ExxdRMW) to my code.

HTML:

```html
<div id="replacement_terminal_dairybeef_toggle">
    <div id="split_calving_toggle_container" >
        <div class="toggle-text">
            <div class="switch"> 

              <input id="togggle_repl_beef" class="checkbox-toggle" data-type="date" type="checkbox"></input>
        <label for="togggle_repl_beef" class="slider round"></label>
              <span class="off">Fade this text when off  </span>
              <span class="on"> Fade this text when on </span>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4.5px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #235b96;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
  transform: translateX(22px);
}


.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.toggle-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #235b96;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.switch {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.off {
  order: 1; 
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 5px;
  order: 2;
}

.on {
  order: 3; 
}

input:checked ~ .on {
  color: red;
}

input:not(:checked) ~ .off {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just link to your code, write a [mcve] of it in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4.5px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #235b96;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
  transform: translateX(22px);
}


.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.toggle-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #235b96;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.switch {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.off {
  order: 1; 
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 5px;
  order: 2;
}

.on {
  order: 3; 
}

input:checked ~ .on {
  color: red;
}

input:not(:checked) ~ .off {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="replacement_terminal_dairybeef_toggle">
 <div id="split_calving_toggle_container" >
  <div class="toggle-text">
   <div class="switch"> 
     
     <input id="togggle_repl_beef" class="checkbox-toggle" data-type="date" type="checkbox"></input>
        <label for="togggle_repl_beef" class="slider round"></label>
     <span class="off">Fade this text when off  </span>
     <span class="on"> Fade this text when on </span>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```